# Can we give a definition of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xdx$,or why this integral is divergent?

Tags: analysis, improper-integrals

I know that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x dx= \int_{-\infty}^{0} xdx + \int_{0}^{\infty} xdx$ and both of these integrals is divergent, so the previous integral is divergent too, but I think it is easy to see that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xdx=0$, what is wrong what is wrong with my intuition?

Comment: What do you propose as a definition for $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\;dx$?

Comment: @Robert $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x dx= \int_{-\infty}^{0} xdx + \int_{0}^{\infty} xdx$

Comment: @Robert I want to know how to get a definition to prove or disprove my intuition..and when we are faced with this expression, what does it stand for ?

Comment: Your intuition is solely based on the symmetry of the function $f(x) = x$, but the issue is that the usual definition of improper integral on $(-\infty, \infty)$ need not be compatible with the symmetry as you can see from Kenny Lau's answer.

Comment: Substituting $x=y+1$ gives $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty (y+1)\,dy$. What does your "intuition" tell you what that integral is.

Answer (score 3):

Saying that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\,dx=0$ is a different way of saying that
$$\infty-\infty=0\ .$$
This is nonsense, because you can't do arithmetic with $\infty$ as if it were a real number.

Another way to look at it: if you insist that for "geometrical" reasons the area given by $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\,dx$ is zero, then you should agree that the following grey area is also zero,
[image]

because it's exactly the same shape, with half of it shifted.  But then the difference between the two areas, yellow in the diagram, must also be zero... I hope you're not believing this any more :)

**Comment**.  I don't know how to crop white space from diagrams, can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Improper integrals are defined as
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \ \text{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^{a} f(x) \ \text{d}x + \int_{a}^{\infty} f(x) \ \text{d}x $$ 
for a set $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

As you said, if either of these two integrals on the RHS do not exist, the LHS does not exist either. However, there is a term for when you can make sense of these integrals despite them not existing. It is said that
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x\ \text{d}x $$
has a $\textbf{Cauchy principal value}$ of 0.

Answer (score 0):

I would define $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty x \ \mathrm dx$ as a double limit, i.e.:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x \ \mathrm dx := \lim_{m \to -\infty} ~ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_m^n x \ \mathrm dx$$

Answer (score -1):

The integral "does not" converges because$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty xdx=\infty-\infty$$this is indeterminate form.

The area closed by the line $y=0$ and the line $y=x$ over all the real numbers is indeed $0$.

Using Cauchy principal value we can find the value of the area, we can take $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-n}^n xdx=0$ but like @KennyLau the integral is defined using double integral $\lim_{n\to\infty\\m\to\infty}\int_{-m}^n xdx=\text{indeterminate}$ because we don't know the relation between $m$ and $n$, if $m=2n$ we will have $\int_{-\infty}^\infty xdx=-\infty$, so we can't determinate the value of this integral solely because of symmetry

Comment: why did my answer got downvote? am i wrong somewhere?

Comment: I don't know. It looks like someone was a jerk and downvoted a bunch of answers without leaving a comment.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Cauchy principal value:

$$\mathsf{P} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x\ dx = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{- 1/\epsilon}^{+1/\epsilon} = \frac{x^2}{2} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{2\epsilon^2} - \frac{1}{2\epsilon^2} = 0$$

Alternatively: $x$ is an odd function, hence its integral between symmetric and opposite values is zero.